# json replace all $regex in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have json say

```
var json= { name: { '$regex': /^Amer$/i }, 'countries.name': { '$regex': /^UNited states$/i } }
```

I want to make it like below bynusing lodash or string/json replace

```
json= { "name": "Amer" , "countries.name": "UNited states" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the RegExps always have the same anchors (`^` and `$`), here is a way to do it:

```js
var json= { name: { '$regex': /^Amer$/i }, 'countries.name': { '$regex': /^UNited states$/i } }

Object.entries(json).forEach(([k, v]) => {
  json[k] = v.$regex.source.slice(1, -1);
})

console.log(json);
```

Comment: Perfect solution, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = { name: { '$regex': /^Amer$/i }, 'countries.name': { '$regex': /^UNited states$/i } };

for(var key in data){
 var value = data[key]['$regex'];
 data[key] = value.source.slice(1, -1)
}

console.log(data);
```